# Binary tree preorder

Tags: c++, data-structures, return, binary-tree, preorder

My preorder method don't work from main, but array elem has been formed rightly (I checked it with printing every step). All functions/methods used in definition work correctly. I think the problem occurs because of line "return elem;". Can anyone suggest any idea, it's too important.

```
T* TreeNode<T>::preorder()const 
{
    T* elem = new T[elCount(left)+elCount(right)+1];
    elem[0] = data;
    TreeNode<T>* curr = left;
    Stack<TreeNode<T>*> st;
    if (right) {
        st.push(right);
    }
    int i = 1;
    while (curr) {
        elem[i++] = curr->getData();
        //std::cout << elem[i - 1];
        
        if (curr->getRight()) 
            st.push(curr->getRight());
        
        curr = curr->getLeft();
        if (!curr) 
        {
            curr = st.getTop();
            st.pop();
        }   }
    return elem;
}
```

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: How are you determining that it doesn't work? (Also, `std::vector` is your friend.)

Comment: If I had a dollar for every time someone (including myself) has said "all these other functions work correctly so the problem must be here" but it turns out that  they don't, I would be a slightly richer man. `return elem;` is definitely not the source of your problems, though.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for advise. I'll take note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to see exactly what you're trying to do as it wasn't specified, but it seems that you're trying to grab all the data from your binary tree. [This GFG article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/) does a really simple explanation and breakdown of how to transverse a binary tree. Obviously your nodes are more complicated, but the general logic is the same. I'd ask yourself as to whether the `preorder()` function really needs to be part of the tree node class and if a separate function wouldn't be a bit more useful. I'd also consider using a `std::vector` rather than the carray you're currently using. If you need the fixed size, `std::array` would probably also work better.

To show how you could possibly rewrite your code you can try something like

```cpp
std::vector<int> vect;

template<class T>
void preorder(const TreeNode<T>& node, vector<T>& elem) {
    if(!node.getData()) {
        return;
    }

    elem.push(node.getData());

    if(node.getLeft()) {
        preorder(node.getLeft());
    }

    if(node.getRight()) {
        preorder(node.getRight());
    }
}
```

This isn't perfect as I wrote this off the top of my head, but it should provide an easy groundwork for traversing the binary tree and pulling out all the data. A little bit of recursion should make it a lot easier.